# jquery checking a radio button based on value

Tags: jquery

I have code that does the following:

```
$("#ProgramLvl:checked").val() == 3
```

How do I actually go about actually selecting the check box?

I know we can do:

```
    $("#ProgramLvl").prop("checked", true);
```

but how do I check it for 3.

Comment: Checkbox is either checked or not. What exactly you want? Select all checked checkboxes with `value` attribute set to `3`?

Comment: @tilz0R Yes correct. Do it for value attribute set to 3.

Comment: Update post with your html. Current selection has no meaning as you are looking for checkbox based on `id` attribute `ProgramLvl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a set of radio buttons, you can access the one you want via its `name` and `value` attributes:

```js
$('input[name="ProgramLvl"][value="3"]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1<input type="radio" name="ProgramLvl" value="1">
2<input type="radio" name="ProgramLvl" value="2"> 
3<input type="radio" name="ProgramLvl" value="3"> 
4<input type="radio" name="ProgramLvl" value="4"> 
5<input type="radio" name="ProgramLvl" value="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the radio button using the following:

```
$('input[type="radio"][value="3"]:checked')
```

Note: I've used `input[type="radio"]` because #ProgramLvl will not work. You are checking for an `id` which will always have only 1 element associated with it.

Assuming your radio buttons have the name of `ProgramLvl`, then you can use the query as:

```
$('input[name="ProgramLvl"][value="3"]:checked')
```